# yarn install throw error request failed \"404 Not found"

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I have react native project that I worked on my laptop. when I transfer the project to my pc and run yarn install (I installed the some modules using yarn and some using npm) I get

> An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jest/-/jest-23.0.0-alpha.0.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".

Yarn version on my pc and latop same

```
1.5.1
```

npm version my pc and latop same

```
5.4.1
```

node version

```
v 7.9.0
```

in addition i get warning when run yarn install on my project

```
warning You are using Node "7.9.0" which is not supported and may encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || >=8.0.0"
```

Comment: What is node version on your laptop?  first of all you should update it on your pc. btw can you show line from packages.json with jest?

Comment: I found a solution, I posted my answer

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I found a solution

```
yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
rm yarn.lock
yarn
```

Comment: I was having the same problem:
`error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/src-map/-/src-map-0.5.7.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".`

And this solution worked for me. This seems like a problem with yarn's dependencies lock

Comment: I had 404 issues with `...yarnpkg.com/serve-...` and this solved it. Is Yarn falling apart after 2.0?

Comment: Watch out, deleting `yarn.lock` can have unintended consequences as it can change the versions of packages installed. Don't casually run this on a real app without checking it doesn't introduce any issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this with a **private** `npm` package, make sure you are logged in with the proper user

run `npm login`

[Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/logging-in-to-an-npm-enterprise-registry-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, getting: 
`An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/es-abstract/-/es-abstract-1.14.0.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".`

Deleting `yarn.lock` and running `yarn` may result in a lot of packages being upgraded, and possibly other configuration issues.

Instead, I just deleted the `es-abstract` resolution section from `yarn.lock`, e.g.:

```
es-abstract@^1.11.0, es-abstract@^1.5.1, es-abstract@^1.7.0:
  version "1.14.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/es-abstract/-/es-abstract-1.14.0.tgz#f59d9d44278ea8f90c8ff3de1552537c2fd739b4"
  integrity sha512-lri42nNq1tIohUuwFBYEM3wKwcrcJa78jukGDdWsuaNxTtxBFGFkKUQ15nc9J+ipje4mhbQR6JwABb4VvawR3A==
  dependencies:
    es-to-primitive "^1.2.0"
    function-bind "^1.1.1"
    has "^1.0.3"
    has-symbols "^1.0.0"
    is-callable "^1.1.4"
    is-regex "^1.0.4"
    object-inspect "^1.6.0"
    object-keys "^1.1.1"
    string.prototype.trimleft "^2.0.0"
    string.prototype.trimright "^2.0.0"
```

and run `yarn`. This solved the issue with a minimal number of upgrades in `yarn.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today in CircleCI, turned out to be a cache problem:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

Actually I had to run `yarn install` twice but no idea why.

Answer (score -7):

following worked for `npm`

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
rm package.json && rm nodemodules
npm install
```

Comment: There's so much wrong with this

Comment: This is nearly a repeat of original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49371861/470818 and confusingly deletes the project's `package.json` file. It also incorrectly treats the path `nodemodules` as a file when it's a directory.