# Vue-fontawesome with Yarn

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, yarnpkg

I've installed all the dependencies to use [Font-Awesome with Vue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome). Nevertheless, I get this error when running `yarn`:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/-/1.2.34/fontawesome-svg-core-1.2.34.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
```

I'm using the free version of Font-Awesome.

Someone has any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: To solve the `401` authentication issue, we can use the solution from this Github thread: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3093#issuecomment-317671597

---

From this [github issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/240) and the answer to it [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8279#issuecomment-669843045), I do understand that this is temporary.

Try it again in a few minutes/hours to see if it's back or try to upgrade your `yarn`.

Also, maybe try just to be sure that it's not on your side

```
yarn cache clean
yarn
```

There is also this other solution, not sure what it's worth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49371861/8816585

Some people fixed their issue by deleting their `yarn.lock` but this one seems a bit too extreme and risky IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried your solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. The thing is that I don't get a 404 but a 401.

Comment: Oops indeed ! In this case, it's a basic authentification issue, try this one: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3093#issuecomment-317671597